# Open CN1Preferences with a text editor

Tags: codenameone

If I try to open the `CN1Preferences` file with a text editor, the result is like the following:

[image]

Is there a text editor capable of reading this file in a "more pleasant" way? I use Linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's an `Extenalizable` output of the preferences object. It's a binary file that can contain non-string data such as images etc. The only editor that you can use is a hex-editor.